# How to autoload a new folder in Laravel 5 using composer.json?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I created a small app using Laravel 5.2. I kept all of my work inside a folder called "Modules" located in `App/Modules`.

Now, I am trying to move out my `Modules` folder to the root directory "outside the App folder." So my `Modules` folder is now located next to the `App`.

I want to auto load the `Modules` folder just like the `App` folder.

To auto load the `Modules, I modified my`autoload`section of my`composer.json` to look like the following:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Modules\\": "modules/"
    }
},
```

Additionally, in the `app.php` config file I added this service provider to my "providers" array

```
Modules\Vendname\Surveys\Providers\CoreValidatorServiceProvider::class,
```

Then from the command line, I executed the following command

```
composer dumpautoload
```

Every time I go to the website, I get this error

```
FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 146: Class 'Modules\Vendname\Surveys\Providers\CoreServiceProvider' not found
```

Here is the code for my CoreServiceProvider.php file

```
<?php

namespace Modules\Vendname\Surveys\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class CoreServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {

        if (! $this->app->routesAreCached()) {
            require __DIR__ . '/../routes.php';
        }

    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {

    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong here?
What do I need to do in order to properly auto load the new folder?

Comment: In which file is the `Modules\Vendname\Surveys\Providers\CoreServiceProvider` class located? According to your `composer.json` file it should be in `modules/Vendname/Surveys/Providers/CoreServiceProvider.php`.

Comment: @xabbuh  I change the name the folder name from "Modules" to "modules" even though it did not solve the problem. thank you for the hint

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it to work.

I commented out the line

```
Modules\Vendname\Surveys\Providers\CoreValidatorServiceProvider::class,
```

in the app.php file.

then in the command line I did the following commands

```
php artisan clear-compiled
composer dumpautoload
composer update
```

Then I uncommented out the line in the app.php file

```
Modules\Vendname\Surveys\Providers\CoreValidatorServiceProvider::class,
```

Comment: `s/compoaser/composer/`